# Conditional Statement inside Lambda Expression c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to remove strings from List by given command.
The command is to remove all strings that starts or ends with given string.

List input = new List() {"Pesho", "Misho", "Stefan"};

string command = "Remove StartsWith P"; or "Remove EndsWith P"

I'm trying to do it with lambda. Smth like this:

```
input.RemoveAll(x =>
{
if (command[1] == "StartsWith")
    x.StartsWith(command[2]);

else if (command[1] == "EndsWith")
    x.EndsWith(command[2]);
});
```

The compiler says:
Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type Predicate

I'm asking is it possible to do it inside one lambda,
or I have to write it for both cases.

Comment: Use following : (command[1] == "StartsWith")? x.StartsWith(command[2]) : (command[1] == "EndsWith") ? x.EndsWith(command[2]) :  "Add Missing Value Here";

Answer (score 6):

The lambda syntax is a function.  Without the `{}` braces the single line present implicitly returns its result, but *with* the braces you need an explicit `return`:

```
input.RemoveAll(x =>
{
    if (command[1] == "StartsWith")
        return x.StartsWith(command[2]);
    else if (command[1] == "EndsWith")
        return x.EndsWith(command[2]);
    else
        return false; // You'll need a default too
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert multiple `if` statements into one `switch` statement and use a `return` for every `case` label

```cs
input.RemoveAll(x =>
{
    switch (command[1])
    {
        case "StartsWith":
            return x.StartsWith(command[2]);
        case "EndsWith":
            return x.EndsWith(command[2]);
        default:
            return false;
    }
});
```

If you can target C# 8, it can be simplified using [`switch` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions)

```cs
input.RemoveAll(x =>
{
    return command[1] switch
    {
        "StartsWith" => x.StartsWith(command[2]),
        "EndsWith" => x.EndsWith(command[2]),
        _ => false
    };
});
```

But in both cases you should maintain a `default` case to return a `false` value